# Applying window based rules in Apache Flink Broadcast stream

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql

I have a set of rules in my BroadcastStream in Apache Flink.
I am able to apply new rules as they come to my stream of events.
But I am not able to figure out how can I implement if my rules are like

```
rule 1> alert when count of event a is greater than 5 in a window of 5 mins
rule 2> alert when count of event a is greater than 4 in a window of 15 mins
```

I am a newbie to flink. I am not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

An application based on flink-sql or flink-cep won't be able to do this, because those libraries can only handle rules that are defined at the time the job is compiled. You would need to start a new job for each new rule, which may not meet your requirements.

If you want to have a single job that can handle a dynamic set of rules that are supplied while the job is running, you'll have to build this yourself. You can use a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` to do this (which it sounds like you have already begun to experiment with).

Here's a sketch of a possible implementation:

You can use keyed state in the KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction to keep track of the current count in each window. If the rules can be characterized by a time interval and a counting threshold, then you could use `MapState`, where the keys are the rule IDs, and the values in the map are the current count for that rule. You can have a timer for each rule that fires when each window ends.

As events arrive, you iterate through the rule-based map, incrementing the counter for every relevant rule. And when the timers fire, you find the relevant rules, compare the counters to the thresholds, take appropriate action, and clear those counters.

Some potential complications to keep in mind:

1. This implementation requires that you partition your stream with a `keyBy`, so that you can use MapState and timers.
2. The broadcast stream can't have timers associated with it, so the timers will have to be managed by the `processElement` method that's handling the keyed stream.
3. Flink only allows one timer for a given key and given timestamp. So take care if you must handle the case where two rules would need to be triggered at the same time.
4. If events can arrive out of order, then you will need to either first sort the stream by timestamp, or allow for having multiple windows open concurrently.